# Excel online: Formulae with structured table references fail with #REF! error when the worksheet is imported using insertWorksheetsFromBase64

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

Repro Steps:

1. Open a new workbook in Excel online
2. Go to script lab and go toimport tab. Paste the code provided in following link and click
   import :
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/excel/50-workbook/workbook-insert-external-worksheets.yaml
3. Trust the code if Excel prompts
4. Run the code Click on 'Choose file',
5. select the file which has formula with structured table reference
6. Click on 'Insert Sheets', it will insert sheet to Excel online.
7. Observe the formulae under the column 'Difference', they fail to
   evaluate and show error #REF!

Repro Results:
Formulae which uses structured table references show error #REF! when the worksheet from local disk is imported to Excel online using insertWorksheetsFromBase64

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, insertFromBase64 API on Excel online is leveraging Copy and Paste capability. structured reference is currently not supported when you copy and paste the same content on Excel online.

Meanwhile, Excel online team keeps improve the Copy and Paste experience. although We do not know when it will be supported, after Excel online Copy and Paste feature support structured reference, insertFromBase64 API will automatically support structured reference.

Therefore, we would suggest that you could use Excel Windows Desktop, or Mac to ensure full parity insertion in this case.